# Работа плагина jquery.ui.sortable в firefox 16-17

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox

Есть менюшка, по клику осуществляется переход по ссылке, также можно перемещать пункты меню.

Т.е. я тыкаю на пункт меню и, не отпуская мыши, перемещаю его повыше. Либо просто кликаю по нему и перехожу по этому пункту.

С обновлением браузера (Firefox) до версии 16, а в последующем и до версии 17beta, появилась проблема: Я тыкаю на пункт меню, перетягиваю его, а когда отпускаю клавишу - срабатывает событие click и я перехожу по ссылке, хотя и не должен. Кто-нибудь с этим ещё столкнулся?

Comment: Проблем не возникало. На всякий случай, [проверил еще раз](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/D2fm3/1/) - клик срабатывает только без перетаскивания объекта. Возможно, что у вас подключены какая-то старенькая или библиотека, или UI. Это всего лишь предположение, но попробуйте обновиться.

Comment: UI стоит версии 1.9
Во всех браузерах отлично работает и в фаерфоксах тоже до 16 версии, а вот начиная с 16 - такой косяк

Comment: @Maxim Li, Не знаю что и добавить. У меня FF 16.0.1 и проблем не обнаружил. Делайте хак, или как посоветовал @istem, или какой-нибудь другой.

Comment: при инициализации плагина указал параметр {helper: "clone"}
этот параметр позволяет перетаскивать не сам элемент, а его клон, на который не повешены никакие события. И костылить не пришлось=)

Answer (score 1):

Повесьте на события mouse флажок, отменяющий переход.
Например:

```
mousedown: flag = true;
mousemove: flag = false;
click: return flag;
```

Хотя здесь вероятны конфликты с тачскринами.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую